# Contour integrals and Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

1) Let $C$ be a contour beginning and ending at 1. Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic on $C$. Then is it true that the contour integral of $f$ around $C$ is 0?

This looks to be true by Cauchy's theorem but I'm not sure about the interior points part of the hypothesis

2) Let $C$ be a contour beginning and ending at 1 and containing numbers whose real part is positive. Then is it true that the integral of $\frac{1}{z^2+z}$ around $C$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have is that $f$ is differentiable on $C$, then $f$ could have singularities elsewhere, each of which would affect the integral of $f$ around $C$ if the winding number of $C$ around it is non-zero. Have you integrated $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ around the unit circle before? That is the most important integral because it tells you essentially what happens at any singularity since the integral is $0$ for all other integral powers.

Also, as you might have noticed, the conditions for Cauchy-Goursat theorem to hold is that the curve must be closed and rectifiable, and the function must be differentiable on a simply connected set that includes the curve. Can you see whether any of the conditions fail to hold for (2)?

Comment: So 1/z around the contour $e^{it}$ $(0{\geq}t{\leq}2{\pi})$ would be a counter example to the first?         As to the second, I'm not sure except there may be a probelm at zero.

Comment: Yes you're done with (1). Real part being positive means that $C$ cannot pass through $0$.

Comment: I think then all conditions hold and it is zero

Comment: @user137090: Yup correct. Note that you just need to make sure the denominator is non-zero on the open right-half plane (which is simply connected).